# Given two sorted arrays of integers, group elements such that the contribution from each array is equal, minimising the sum of leftover values

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, grouping, matching

**Problem**

Given two sorted arrays of positive integers `A1` and `A2`:

- Group elements from each array such that the contribution to each group from each array are equal
- Do so in such a way that minimises the sum of ungrouped elements left over in each array

---

**Example**

Given the following two arrays:

`A1 = [1, 4, 6, 9, 45, 128]` 
`A2 = [1, 9, 10, 11, 14, 20, 512, 512]`

We group elements from `A1` (LHS) and `A2` (RHS) as follows:

`[1],[1]` 
`[4,6],[10]` 
`[9],[9]` 
`[45],[11,14,20]`

Whereby:

- `128` is the sum leftover from `A1`
- `1024` (`512` + `512`) is the sum leftover from `A2`

Hence the minimised leftover is `128 + 1024 = 1152`

---

**Conditions**

- All values are positive
- Duplicates are allowed in each array
- Both arrays are assumed to have at least one element
- Arrays can be of different sizes, and contain no more than 10,000 elements
- There can be more than one optimal solution that minimises the leftover

---

**Bonus**

Solve the same problem but for an arbitrary `n` arrays of positive integers.

Comment: What would be the result of `A1 = [1, 3, 6, 8, 100, 200], A2 = [2, 7, 10, 400]`? Would it be `[3, 6, 8], [7, 10]` with `1, 100, 200` leftover from `A1` and `2, 400` leftover from `A2`? If so, I don't think your algorithm of using the max value as the target will work. Also, post the runtime if your constraints are not given - "No upper bound on the size of the array" doesn't help at all; if the size of the arrays is unbounded, we can't even read the content of just one of the arrays without timing out.

Comment: Thank you, points taken. I have updated the conditions to be more specific, and have changed the goal to be more well-defined. Target is now to to minimise the sum of the leftover values. There's more than one way to do reach the minimum, but there'll only be one minimum.

Comment: I also agree that my solution may not be sufficient to minimise the leftover, so I am omitting it until I can think of something better.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Can't guarantee that I'll be able to come up with a solution that'll meet your constraints but will think about it a bit. Although your initial attempt might not quite be correct It is worth keeping it since it shows you've at least put some effort into the issue.

Comment: As a hint, based on the array sizes being limited to `10**4` it looks like a quadratic algorithm might be acceptable.

Comment: The problem is equivalent to finding the maximum [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) that's common to both arrays. In your example, the **maximum common subset sum** is 55. So you can simply group the elements as `[1,4,6,9,35],[1,9,10,11,14,20]`, leaving `[128,512,512]` as the leftovers. Whether or not the problem is solvable in sub-exponential time depends on the sum of the elements in the arrays.